# sql query to swap columns if 1 is greater than other

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 columns where there's a number in them if column 1 has a larger number than column 2 I want to swap the values between these 2 columns.

Is there an easy way to do this with a query?

start:

```
id | column 1 | column 2
------------------------
1   50         3
2   51         4
```

finish:

```
id | column 1 | column 2
------------------------
1   3          50
2   4          51
```

Comment: Just use a case statements (or an ifs for less clarity).

Comment: @P.Salmon I am not that experienced, unfortunately I don't know what that means? I don't know how many swaps I need to do beforehand

Comment: OK publish some sample data and desired output as text. AND expand on what you mean by 'I don't know how many swaps I need to do beforehand'

Comment: Use GREATEST/LEAST functions in UPDATE.

Comment: @P.Salmon I updated OP

Comment: You need to be clear what you mean by query - a SELECT.. is a query and an UPDATE.. is a query

Answer (score 2):

You can't just swap values. You need temporary variable
First way:

```
 UPDATE table_name SET column1=column2, column2=@temp WHERE (@temp:=column1) > column2;
```

Second way: This way is better because it check is any value is NULL

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1=(@temp:=column1), column1= column2, column2 = @temp WHERE column1 > column2;
```

Second way is simple. It compare two cols and swap this cols if needs.

Comment: If it helps you, please let me know.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't paying attention. I had removed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In an `UPDATE` statement MySql uses non standard SQL behavior when it comes to the use of values of the updated columns, because in a statement like this:

```
SET a = x, b = a
```

the value of `a` in the assignment `b = a` will not be the original value that is stored in the table, but the value of `a` after the assignment `a = x`.
So this:

```
update tablename
set column1 = column2,
    column2 = column1
```

that would work in other databases does not work in MySql.

There is a workaround that does not use variables or unnecessary joins:

```
update tablename
set column1 = column1 + column2,
    column2 = column1 - column2,
    column1 = column1 - column2
where column1 > column2;
```

which works since:

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to
>   right.

(from [13.2.13 UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html))

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/swxmF3fUtwfoNwLwVWoqEq/1).
Results:

```
| id  | column1 | column2 |
| --- | ------- | ------- |
| 1   | 3       | 50      |
| 2   | 4       | 51      |
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a primary key on the table, so a simple option is `join`:

```
update t join
       t t2
       on t.id = t2.id
    set t.x = t2.y, 
        t.y = t2.x
    where t.x > t.y;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=156fc8cc08e1231a2fa63b6470995c92) is a db<>fiddle.

I prefer this method to using variables for several reasons:

1. This does not depend on the order of evaluations of the `set` clauses, which I don't think that MySQL guarantees.
2. I think this use of variables is deprecated in MySQL 8+
3. It does not depend on the ordering of the expressions, so it is more robust and readily adapts to more complicated expressions.